# Javascript Date Selection

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm currently trying to make a day selection for my website and I'm having a slight issue with it. My current issue stands at this.

The if statement at the bottom doesn't seem to be searching and selecting data that contains that? I'm not great with javascript so I'm not too sure if that's how you would do it?

Overall I want it so that it selects all classes with the name **show** and then searches the contents of it to see if it's equal to todays date, if so it will colour it green. I've tried thinking of different ways I can do this but I can't seem to get my head around it and I've also looked on here to see if anyone's trying to make something simular but their all date selections, not day selections.

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
        function showDate()
        {
            var now = new Date();
            var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
            var shows = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
            var today = shows.innerHTML;
            var showElements = document.querySelectorAll('show');

            document.getElementById('dateToday').innerHTML = 'Today is: ' + dayNames[now.getDay()];

            if(today.contains(dayNames[now.getDay()]))
            {
                showElements.style.color = '#00E42D';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="active">
    <h1>Active Shows</h1>
    <li id="SOA" class="show"><strong>Sons of Anarchy</strong> - Tuesday</small></li>
    <li id="SP" class="show"><strong>Southpark</strong> - Wednesday</li>
    <li id="WLR" class="show"><strong>Waterloo Road</strong> - Wednesday</li>
    <li id="TWD" class="show"><strong>The Walking Dead</strong> - Sunday</li>
    <li id="FG" class="show"><strong>Family Guy</strong> - Sunday</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are solutions, but the best way is just adding a class (or data attribute) to the list-items witch day it is. Than you only have to get the element by id. Also, can't you do this serverside and add a `today` class? Than there is no need for Javascript

Comment: Where is the ID called `dateToday` or what is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Brendan That's just to display today's date, doesn't do anything other than just letting me know the function was working.

Comment: @AndreasFurster If I did it serverside, wouldn't it just return the  day of where the server is? I'm not too sure

Comment: @SirTiggs, your right about that. But you can set the day as classname. This makes a lot nicer code and is better in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its easy to use jQuery

Here is the js code :

```
<script>
    function showDate() {
      var now = new Date();
      var dayNames = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
      var today = dayNames[now.getDay()];
      $('dateToday').html( 'Today is: ' + today);
      $(".show:contains("+today+")").css("color","#00E42D");

    }
  </script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QJn6BKQCEkHljuDvic4L?p=preview

Comment: Yeah but does he want JQuery?

Comment: jQuery is a helper library that minimize your code and supports cross browsers